# Semantic value of "For all ... exists..." - Minimum of a maximum

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I can't for the life of me figure this out myself, even though I know the answer.

Consider an expression $\forall x\exists y\,gt(x,y)$ where 
$$
gt(x,y):=
\begin{cases}
1, &x>y\\
0, &\mathrm{else}
\end{cases},
$$
and where we, for the sake of simplicity, assume that we're in $\mathbb{R}$. The semantic value (i.e. the "truth"-value)of this is then $1$, but how do we compute it? It boils down to the expression

$$
\min_x\left\{\max_y\left\{gt(x,y)\right\}\right\}.
$$
This is my problem. I feel pretty darn stupid right now, because an expression like this should be solvable even for a fresher, I guess - which I am not. But my entire way of thinking is flawed right now, and also the universe seems to collapse.

I don't see how I can compute the maximum of a set that still depends on another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an $x$; can we find an $y$ such that $x > y$ ?

Yes, of course; it is enough to choose as $y$ the value $x-1$. Then we have at least one value for $y$ such that $gt(x,y)=1$.

Then, for sure :

> $$\max_y\left\{gt(x,y)\right\}=1.$$

The above argument hold for **any** $x$, i.e. : for all $x, \max_y\left\{gt(x,y)\right\}=1$.

Thus :

> > $$\min_x\left\{\max_y\left\{gt(x,y)\right\}\right\}=1.$$

Comment: Uhm... duh. I don't even know why I didn't see this. Might as well give up now. Thanks!